# MassTransit consumer fault handling when the destination system is down for long time

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have read the MT documentation on Error handling and faults and put some code to publish the fault and written a fault consumer to listen to the fault message after some number of retries with Polly.

I have a queue consumer gets the messages from RabbitMQ using MassTranasit and send to a cloud system through Http api. I have handled all possible exceptions and also wrapped http calls in Polly retry for transient network errors. But the problem with this approach is the message is literally abandoned from processing after the retries exhausted.

If the destination system is down for 10 hrs assume( this outage we don't know before otherwise i will plan for consumer service stop), what is the best strategy we can put with MassTransit to stop pulling the messages from Queue into Consumer? Is there a way we can stop receiving the messages based on number of failures etc..?

Thanks

Comment: You should use MassTransit's retry support instead of "polly" as Alexey stated below, an you should have monitoring in place to detect these errors (from the logs) and stop the service to avoid cycling every message through the queue only to have to shovel them back into the queue (from _error) once the service is available.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your comment. Could you please check my comment on using Polly instead of  MT retries below on Alexey reply? Does that makes sense?

Comment: I support Chris' point with regards to monitoring. If you abstract the remote system client and observe its behaviour using health checks, you can also make your service unhealthy and deal with it from the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a circuit breaker, it's a well-known pattern in distributed systems. The circuit breaker activates when the remote system is struggling under load and putting more requests to it will potentially strangle it. It would also allow you to stop sending messages to the remote system when it is down.

The circuit breaker is [available in MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/circuit-breaker.html#circuit-breaker) out of the box.

I would also not recommend implementing retries using Polly in the consumer. MassTransit has a comprehensive set of retry policies and it also allows MassTransit to understand how many failures occur in the consumer, which is not available when you use Polly. For example, the circuit breaker middleware won't know about failures in a Polly-wrapped call and therefore won't be reacting properly.

If the remote system is down for a long time (like hours, as you described), any retry policy with a limited number of attempts will eventually fail. The circuit breaker will open but it would reset from time to time and try sending calling the consumer again. Otherwise, it won't ever know when the remote system is recovered. So, you would either need to recover messages from the error queue or add the [redelivery](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery) middleware.

You can therefore configure your receive pipeline this way:

redelivery -> circuit breaker -> retry -> consumer

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for the reply. There is a reason for me to use Polly instead of MT message retry, With MT retries the whole code in consumer gets executed every time and I know only the code I need to retry is outgoing http call to destination system at the last point and everywhere else if I get exception it cannot be solved by retrying. 
So does that makes sense to use Polly or do you still have strong opinion to use MT retry here? 

Thanks

Comment: And also regarding retrying, like you mentioned we have couple options here. 1. Use _Error queue and move them back to normal queue manually later 2. Use RabbitMQ deferred schedule to redeliver after certain time. I like this schedule but I am not sure exactly the time to schedule the message as the destination system outage is not in our hands. Which one do you think is the better one?

Comment: I see. You have an option to split the operation bound to the HTTP call in a separate consumer and send a message to yourself from the original consumer. In regards to redelivery, as well as for retries, you can configure incremental or exponential retries, so the timeout between retries will increase, just make sure it won't get undesirably long. If you want to stick to Polly, you can use Polly own circuit breaker as well. Basically, the circuit breaker is what you need, you just need to find out on which level you want to apply it.